# Sqoop Merge - Update records using incremental import

Tags: merge, sqoop

I am trying to understand the Merge option in sqoop, but unable to comprehend the same. My basic understanding about the merge option is that it can update the records based on the id key.

```
create table customer (id int, name varchar(100), recorddt date);
insert into customer values (1,'abc','2016-01-01');
insert into customer values (2,'def','2016-01-02');
```

After this extracted the records using incremental-append option. Both the records are extracted.

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/training_db  \
--username root \
--password cloudera \
--table customer \
--target-dir '/user/cloudera/kbk/sqoop1' \
--incremental append \
--check-column id \
--last-value 0 \
--m 1
```

Output of the  above script

```
[cloudera@quickstart sqoop_scripts]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera/kbk/sqoop1
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera         34 2017-01-01 05:49 /user/cloudera/kbk/sqoop1/part-m-00000
[cloudera@quickstart sqoop_scripts]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/kbk/sqoop1/part-m-00000
1,abc,2016-01-01
2,def,2016-01-02
[cloudera@quickstart sqoop_scripts]$
```

Update one record

```
update customer set name = 'abcxyz', recorddt = '2016-01-04' where id = 1;

mysql> select * from customer;
+------+--------+------------+
| id   | name   | recorddt   |
+------+--------+------------+
|    1 | abcxyz | 2016-01-04 |
|    2 | def    | 2016-01-02 |
+------+--------+------------+
```

After this, extracted the record using incremental-lastmodified option using the below script.

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/training_db \
--username root \
--password cloudera \
--table customer \
--target-dir '/user/cloudera/kbk/sqoop2' \
--incremental lastmodified \
--check-column recorddt \
--last-value '2016-01-03' \
--merge-key id \
--m 1
```

In the above script for the target-dir, if I use the same location as that of the previous script, the script throws an error telling that the location exists and then re-runs and generates a part-r-00000 file with all the records. So changed the location to a new path and executed the same.

```
17/01/01 05:54:48 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 20 bytes in 31.8766 seconds (0.6274 bytes/sec)
17/01/01 05:54:48 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 1 records.
17/01/01 05:54:48 INFO tool.ImportTool: Final destination exists, will run merge job.
17/01/01 05:54:48 INFO tool.ImportTool: Moving data from temporary directory _sqoop/be32a583f44e47ebbde872e58513d40f_customer to final destination 

/user/cloudera/kbk/sqoop2
17/01/01 05:54:48 INFO tool.ImportTool: Incremental import complete! To run another incremental import of all data following this import, supply the following 

arguments:
17/01/01 05:54:48 INFO tool.ImportTool:  --incremental lastmodified
17/01/01 05:54:48 INFO tool.ImportTool:   --check-column recorddt
17/01/01 05:54:48 INFO tool.ImportTool:   --last-value 2017-01-01 05:54:16.0
17/01/01 05:54:48 INFO tool.ImportTool: (Consider saving this with 'sqoop job --create')
```

Output of the above script

```
[cloudera@quickstart sqoop_scripts]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera/kbk/sqoop2
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera          0 2017-01-01 05:54 /user/cloudera/kbk/sqoop2/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera         20 2017-01-01 05:54 /user/cloudera/kbk/sqoop2/part-m-00000
[cloudera@quickstart sqoop_scripts]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/kbk/sqoop2/part-m-00000
1,abcxyz,2016-01-04
```

I am able to understand the incremental option and but not able to clearly catch how this merge works. I am clearly missing something to fully understand this. What am I missing to understand how the merge works (the record is updated for the record with id as 1). Where will that be updated ? Or is there any other specific step to do  that update at the record level (Now here we are having two records for the same ID 1 in two different directories). Is there a possibility that the update happens and we are left only with one record (the updated record).

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer myself.

We can use the sqoop merge option to perform the same. Using the .java class that is generated when the data is imported, the class and the jar can be used to perform the merge activity.

Comment: Are you talking about merge tool which merges old and new data ??